# How to convert OpenCv Mat to webrtc::VideoFrame(I420Buffer) in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, webrtc

I learned how to convert webrtc::VideoFrame to OpenCv Mat by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607268/how-to-convert-webrtcvideoframe-to-opencv-mat-in-c). After modifying some part of the data, I want to send back as a videoFrame (webrtc::I420Buffer) via WebRTC.
How can we convert OpenCV mat to webrtc::VideoFrame?

```cpp
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> MatToI420(cv::Mat& cvMat, const int buf_width, const int buf_height){

    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> buffer;
    buffer = webrtc::I420Buffer::Create(buf_width, buf_height, buf_width, (buf_width + 1) / 2, (buf_width + 1) / 2);

    //Test. make it a black screen -> succeeded.
    //webrtc::I420Buffer::SetBlack(buffer.get());

    //This is not working yet.
    //cv::Mat yuv;
    //cv::cvtColor(cvMat, yuv, CV_BGRA2YUV_I420);
    //const int conversionResult = libyuv::ConvertToI420(
    //    yuv.ptr(), CalcBufferSize(webrtc::VideoType::kARGB, buf_width, buf_height)
    //    , buffer->MutableDataY(), buffer->StrideY()
    //    , buffer->MutableDataU(), buffer->StrideU()
    //    , buffer->MutableDataV(), buffer->StrideV()
    //    , 0, 0
    //    , buf_width, buf_height
    //    , buf_width, buf_height
    //    , libyuv::kRotate0,
    //    libyuv::FOURCC_ARGB
    //);

    //strange video....
    //buffer = webrtc::I420Buffer::Copy(
    //    buf_width, buf_height
    //    , cvMat.data, cvMat.cols
    //    , cvMat.data + cvMat.rows * cvMat.cols, cvMat.cols / 2
    //    , cvMat.data + cvMat.rows * cvMat.cols + ((cvMat.rows / 2) * (cvMat.cols / 2)), cvMat.cols / 2
    //);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: IDK what manner of data the webrtc thingy wants but you can just access the flat data in a Mat. make sure to consider who owns the memory. you can construct Mats that don't own (will not delete) the memory they refer to. in general, Mat will allocate, own, and delete its memory. you are allowed to use a Mat's memory for the lifetime of the Mat.

Comment: if you figured out an answer to your own question, you should preferably post that as an Answer. self-answering is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example. Try it.

```cpp
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

extern "C" {
    //Required for using sws_scale
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

#include "api/scoped_refptr.h"
#include "api/video/i420_buffer.h"
#include "api/video/video_frame_buffer.h"
#include "api/video/video_rotation.h"
#include "modules/video_capture/video_capture_factory.h"

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607268/how-to-convert-webrtcvideoframe-to-opencv-mat-in-c
cv::Mat I420ToMat(webrtc::I420Buffer* inputBuffer) {
    cv::Mat result;
    struct SwsContext* sws_ctx = NULL;
    sws_ctx = sws_getContext(inputBuffer->width(), inputBuffer->height(), AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
        inputBuffer->width(), inputBuffer->height(),
        AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
        NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (sws_ctx == nullptr){ return result; }

    AVFrame* pBGRFrame = av_frame_alloc();  //Allocate frame, because it is more continent than allocating and initializing data buffer and linesize.
    pBGRFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;
    pBGRFrame->width = inputBuffer->width();
    pBGRFrame->height = inputBuffer->height();
    int sts = av_frame_get_buffer(pBGRFrame, 0);    //Buffers allocation
    if (sts < 0){ return result; }
    const uint8_t* const src_data[] = { inputBuffer->DataY(), inputBuffer->DataU(), inputBuffer->DataV() };
    const int src_stride[] = { inputBuffer->StrideY(), inputBuffer->StrideU(), inputBuffer->StrideV() };
    sts = sws_scale(sws_ctx, src_data, src_stride, 0, inputBuffer->height(), pBGRFrame->data, pBGRFrame->linesize);
    if (sts != inputBuffer->height()){ return result; }

    result = cv::Mat(pBGRFrame->height, pBGRFrame->width, CV_8UC3, pBGRFrame->data[0], pBGRFrame->linesize[0]).clone();    //cv::Mat is OpenCV "thin image wrapper".

    //Free
    sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
    av_frame_free(&pBGRFrame);
    return result;
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291740/sws-scale-generates-malformed-video
rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> MatToI420(cv::Mat cvMat, const int width, const int height)
{
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> result;
    int out_linesize[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    uint8_t* out_planes[4] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };
    int sts = av_image_alloc(out_planes, out_linesize, width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 1);
    if (sts < 0){ return result; }
    struct SwsContext* sws_context = nullptr;
    sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_context, width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
        SWS_BILINEAR, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (sws_context == nullptr){ return result; }
    const int in_linesize[3] = { 3 * width, 0, 0 };
    const uint8_t* in_planes[1] = { cvMat.data };
    int response = sws_scale(sws_context, in_planes, in_linesize, 0, height, out_planes, out_linesize);
    if (response < 0){ return result; }

    /*
    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f, "yuv420p_image.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(out_planes[0], 1, width * height, f);
    fwrite(out_planes[1], 1, width * height / 4, f);
    fwrite(out_planes[2], 1, width * height / 4, f);
    fclose(f);
    //.\ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 640x480 -pixel_format yuv420p -i yuv420p_image.bin rgbcheck.png
    */

    result = webrtc::I420Buffer::Copy(
        width, height
       ,out_planes[0], width
       ,out_planes[1], width / 2
       ,out_planes[2], width / 2
    );

    av_freep(out_planes);
    sws_freeContext(sws_context);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    //Create raw video frame in I420 format using FFmpeg (for testing):
    //ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:duration=1:rate=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo I420.yuv
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int stride_y = width;
    int stride_u = width / 2;
    int stride_v = width / 2;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> data_y_ (new uint8_t[width * height]);
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> data_u_ (new uint8_t[width * height / 4]);
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> data_v_ (new uint8_t[width * height / 4]);
    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f, "I420.yuv", "rb");
    fread(data_y_.get(), 1, width * height, f);  //Read Y color channel.
    fread(data_u_.get(), 1, width * height / 4, f);  //Read U color channel.
    fread(data_v_.get(), 1, width * height / 4, f);  //Read V color channel.
    fclose(f);

    // [i420 -> cv::Mat] -> i420 -> cv::Mat

    //make a (webrtc::I420Buffer) buffer  
    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> i420buffer = webrtc::I420Buffer::Create(width, height, stride_y, stride_u, stride_v);
    i420buffer = webrtc::I420Buffer::Copy(width, height, data_y_.get(), stride_y, data_u_.get(), stride_u, data_v_.get(), stride_v);
    cv::Mat matImg = I420ToMat(i420buffer.get());

    //Use OpenCV for showing the image
    cv::imshow("cvImg", matImg);
    cv::waitKey();

    //Save the inage in PNG format using OpenCV
    cv::imwrite("rgb1.png", matImg);

    // i420 -> [cv::Mat -> i420] -> cv::Mat

    rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::I420Buffer> new_buffer = webrtc::I420Buffer::Create(width, height, stride_y, stride_u, stride_v);
    new_buffer = MatToI420(matImg, width, height);

    // i420 -> cv::Mat -> [i420 -> cv::Mat]

    cv::Mat matImg2 = I420ToMat(new_buffer.get());

    cv::imshow("cvImg2", matImg2);
    cv::waitKey();

    //Save the inage in PNG format using OpenCV
    cv::imwrite("rgb2.png", matImg2);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```